# How can you make Minecraft look like it did back in the Alpha stages?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft Alpha used to have a brighter texture. How can you apply these bright, vivid colors to today's Minecraft? I am aware that there is a Biomes O' Plenty biome which is like this, but I want it to be like this everywhere I go. Turning up the brightness does not achieve the desired effect.

How Minecraft looked back in Alpha:
[image]

How Minecraft looks today:
[image]

Comment: So you took a picture of a superflat world and repeaters to compare it to a lush, hilly biome??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a Classic Minecraft resource pack just for this reason!

[Download here!](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1867509-classic-minecraft-resource-pack-sounds-16/)

Comment: So is this a mod or just sounds and textures.

Comment: Resource pack is sounds and textures, yep.

Comment: Will this work if mods are installed, or if used with a mod pack?

Comment: @jeffreylin_ if there are items/mobs etc introduced by the mod, they will not be retextured. However, the default game textures should still be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You can back date your minecraft to when it was alpha: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/106402-tool-cyborgs-tools-mcnostalgia-104/

Comment: Question says "to today's Minecraft"...